# How to use reset counter in kernel module programming every second?

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel-module

how can i use jiffies interrupts to reset some other kernel variable counter in a kernel module.

I am trying to reset some counter every second...just to check that i reach certain threshold every second.not sure how to approach this in kernel module programming.

some explanation with an example will be highly appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Go for kernel timers or delayed works.. :)

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
unsigned long later = jiffies + 5*HZ;         /* five seconds from now */
if (jiffies > later) { 
 counter++
}
```

Alternatively, I would recommend consider using some well known macros, as the above code is could cause overflows.

```
time_after(j,t) here the macro returns true if time jiffies j is after time t; otherwise, it returns false.
time_before(j, t), 
time_after_eq(j, t),
time_before_eq(j, t)
```

Comment: What if `later` overflows? You should definitely use the macros provided instead of rolling your own.

Comment: @tangrs, Correct, the initial code was only for giving and overview. It always recommend to use the macros provided to avoid overflow.